# The type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, sql, .net-4.0

I recently need to do an upgrade on my project from .net 3.5 to .net 4 and connect to the new SQL server 2008 R2. After I upgrade and compile, it throws these 2 errors:

Interop type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

The type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass' has no constructors defined

the code throw out this error is on the ApplicationClass:
IDTSApplication90 app = new ApplicationClass();

I have this dll in the bin folder: Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll
This dll's version is 9.0.242.0

I think .NET 4 doesn't like it. So I ask our DBA to search this file in the server to look for version 10. She told me this file doesn't exist in the sql server.

What do I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For 2008 R2 correct version of this dll is 10.50.1600.1 and I've got it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies. Try searching there.

Comment: I finally found a dll in my local box. However, this problem still not resolved after I change IDTSApplication90 to IDTSApplication100. Someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

According [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms198536):

> The Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper namespace provides the
>   classes and interfaces used to create Control Flow components in the
>   runtime. This assembly is a Primary Interop Assembly (PIA) for the
>   namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime, which is the assembly
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS (in
>   microsoft.sqlserver.manageddts.dll). **The classes in this namespace
>   should not be instantiated. Instead, use the classes found in the
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime**.

I think you should rewrite your code to use classes from [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime) namespace. [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application) from this namespace can be instantiated - I've used it.
Example which loads and executes package you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx).

Comment: rewrite really isn't an option for me. Is there a solution for upgrading from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4 regarding this without touching the code?